# Checking if at least one file in folder has a newer modified date

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a batch file/PowerShell script that compares the last modified date between a file in folder A and a bunch of files in folder B. If the script finds a more recent file in folder B, then stop comparing and run XYZ. Otherwise, do nothing.

So far, after going over a bunch of related posts, I came up with the following PowerShell script.

```
$pdf = "T:\Sample_Folder\PDF\*.pdf"
$pdfTime = (Get-Item $pdf).LastWriteTime
$source = "T:\Sample_Folder\Sources"
Get-ChildItem $source | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.LastWriteTime -gt $pdfTime -and $_.Mode -ne "d----") {
        echo "Hello!"
    }
}
```

The code seems to correctly check the last modified date of `$pdf` and of `$source` folder children. But what I need is to stop the loop once a more recent file is found in `$source` and go to the action (echo in this example).
How do I stop the loop once the first more recent file is found in `$source`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use a `break` statement on a line after the echo statement.

Comment: Another option is to just sort by `lastwritetime` and pick the top entry: `... | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending`.

Comment: Hi  AdminOfThings, thank you for your response and for your suggestion! It works. But I am just curious how to write the code so that it will say if at least one file in $source has a more recent modified date than the file in the $pdf folder, then do XYZ. Thank you again!

Comment: It seems like you are already doing that. Are you asking to make the script output "I found a newer file." And then do XYZ?

Comment: `if((Get-ChildItem $source -File|Where-Object LastWriteTime -gt $pdfTime).Count -gt 0){xyz}`

Comment: Hi AdminOfThings, thank you for your response! I just want to exit the loop once the first recently modified file is found in sources and do XYZ.

Comment: Hi LotPings, thank you for your suggestion! Could you please explain what .Count does here? Thank you!